# Call graphql query from form submit

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have a simple react app like

```
const [shoe, setShoe] = useState('')

formSubmit = () => {
    e.preventDefault()
        const { data } = useQuery<GetShoeDetailsQuery,GetShoeDetailsQueryVariables>(getShoeDetailsQuery, {
            variables: {
                name: String(shoe),
            },
        })
        console.log(data)
}

<form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
    <input type="text"
        onChange: (e: { target: { value: SetStateAction<string> } }) => {
            setShoe(e.target.value)
        },
    >
    <button></button>
</form>
```

so when the form is submitted it makes a graphql call

my problem is I get an error `react-dom.development.js:14906 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for on`

How can I call the useQuery after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what library you are using to work with GraphQL. If it is from apollo: Use `useLazyQuery` instead of `useQuery`

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery

Comment: That's still a hook and has to abide by the same rules

Comment: @MichelFloyd thats still a hook but it has different usage. It has examples how to use. It returns a callback that can be used on any event, the hook itself is called on top level.

Comment: And `useQuery` also allows you to `refetch` on user action…

Comment: @MichelFloyd it is true, I am not sure what is the difference between them (maybe ```useQuery``` reads from cache but ```useLazyQuery``` does not, before gets called). ```useLazyQuery```is created especially for this case., but with ```useLazyQuery``` you have to do it manually with ```skip``` and ```refetch```

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery): "The useLazyQuery hook is perfect for executing queries in response to events besides component rendering. Unlike with useQuery, when you call useLazyQuery, it does not immediately execute its associated query. Instead, it returns a query function in its result tuple that you call whenever you're ready to execute the query."

Comment: Isn't it exactly what is asked in the question

Comment: Correct - I think you might expand on your answer by showing the OP what their code would look like using the useLazyQuery hook. Yours should be the accepted answer if it had code and not just a pointer to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refetch` of useQuery.

```
const [shoe, setShoe] = useState('')
const { data, refetch } = useQuery(getShoeDetailsQuery, {
    variables: {
        name: String(shoe),
    },
})

formSubmit = () => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    refetch();
}

<form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
    <input type="text"
        onChange: (e => {
          setShoe(e.target.value)
        },
    >
    <button></button>
</form>
```

In this case, the data will be fetched automatically when `shoe` changes.
You can disable this query from automatically running by setting `skip`: true.

```
const { data, refetch } = useQuery(getShoeDetailsQuery, {
    variables: {
        name: String(shoe),
    },
    skip: true,
})
```